# Connecting the neo4j web client to a local database

Tags: neo4j, database-connection, local-database

I've created a boatload of nodes in my neo4j database and I've been happily querying them. Everything's working great, but I don't see how to get the web interfaced attached to my local database – terminology doesn't seem to be super consistent in the neo4j documentation, so I'm using it in the context of:

```
~$ /opt/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell -? | grep -e '^ \-path'
-path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
```

The web server just seems interested in the database in data/graph.db. I feel like `:server connect` should have some option to connect to a different local database, but it's not evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux/MacOS, edit `neo4j-server.properties` from the `conf` directory of your Neo4j installation and change the value of `org.neo4j.server.database.location` to point to your local database.

The `neo4j-shell` you refer to above does not affect the web browser, and you can use it to connect to an existing running database, or to another remote database or start a local database if not already running and connect to it, see http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/re02.html#shell-manpage

Comment: Hey, sorry, @Luanne, I didn't see this. I was just sent back to this question because I got 1000 views. I'll mark this answer as correct and take it as a task to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what OS you're using, but I'm on Windows, and when I run `bin\neo4j-community.exe` I get this dialog box that lets me choose the database location:

[image]

Comment: I'm on a MacBook. Darwin. Yosemite. I'm a recent convert from Ubuntu, and I don't know how to answer the question. OS X? In any case, neo4j does not give me a popup.

Comment: Oh! How would i run two browser tabs pointing at different local dbs? I don't think it's a neo4j server configuration issue. The client needs to be able to switch databases.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have multiple db's loaded at once.. maybe you could try running two instances of neo4j on different ports?